# Get bid/ask price from Interactive Brokers using python

Tags: python

This code:

```
ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 7496)

contract = Stock('SLV', 'SMART', 'USD')

test=ib.reqTickers(contract) 
print(test)
```

will print out this:

```
[Ticker(contract=Stock(symbol='SLV', exchange='SMART', currency='USD'), time=datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 1, 15, 18, 43, 287622, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc), bid=14.26, bidSize=11224, ask=14.27, askSize=2970, last=14.27, lastSize=1, volume=48694, open=14.24, high=14.33, low=14.24, close=14.33, halted=0.0, ticks=[], tickByTicks=[], domBids=[], domAsks=[], domTicks=[])]
```

Now I need to get the bid and ask prices.

Doing `print(test.ask)` or `print(test.bid)` normally gets error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'ask'.

I tried many other things similar to the above but got similar errors.

Comment: Please give a [mcve]. You seem to be using definitions and imports that you have not shown.

Comment: Yes this is an Interactive Brokers feature that I have successfully developed. I got the correct object with the [Ticker] information. But if you think there is something within the IB realm that is preventing me from simply doing a print (test.ask) then I will need to probably post on their specialized forums (though their response time is slow). Thanks for your input I clarified my answer some.

Answer (score 3):

Your `test` is a list of length 1 whose only entry is the `Ticker` object that you are interested in. Try `test[0].ask`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, solved this way:

*test*, in your example, is a list of Ticker objects. Also, in your example, *contract* contains a single contract, but would more commonly contain a group of contracts (**contracts*), as per the ib_insync documents [here](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html?highlight=reqtickers#ib_insync.ib.IB.reqTickers).

The following code is a solution:

```
test = ib.reqTickers(contract)
for _, r in enumerate(test):
    print(r.contract.symbol, r.time, r.bid, r.ask, r.close)
```

The better code (also per the documents link) would be:

```
tickers = [ib.reqTickers(*contracts)]
for i, r in enumerate(tickers):
    for j, t in enumerate(r):
        print(t.contract.symbol, t.time, t.bid, t.ask, t.close)
```